# HTML/CSS text formatting: Assigning h1 "MyCloud" but "My" be white and "Cloud" be blue

Tags: html, css, formatting

Essentially I need to figure out how to Create a large black box and then on top of it I want to have the text "MyCloud" with the "My" being white and the "Cloud" being another color. I got the text to finally be different colors but now the black box has disappeared.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MyCloud</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        <div myCloud>
            <span style="color: red">My</span><span style="color: blue;">Cloud</span>
        </div>
    </h1>
    <h2>Completed Projects:</h2>
    <h3>Contact Us</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

```
*{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.myCloud{
    background-color: black;
}
h2{
    background-color: #6331a8;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
h3{
    color: black;
    background-color: #599ed4;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You currently have:

```
<h1>
    <div myCloud>
        <span style="color: red">My</span><span style="color: blue;">Cloud</span>
    </div>
</h1>
```

Looks like you forgot `class=` before `myCloud`.

Try this:

```
<h1>
    <div class="myCloud">
        <span style="color: red">My</span><span style="color: blue;">Cloud</span>
    </div>
</h1>
```

**EDIT:** You were setting all background colors to be white with the `*` style at the top of your stylesheet.

```css
.myCloud{
    background-color: black;
}
h2{
    background-color: #6331a8;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
h3{
    color: black;
    background-color: #599ed4;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MyCloud</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="myCloud">
            <span style="color: red">My</span><span style="color: blue;">Cloud</span>
    </h1>
    <h2>Completed Projects:</h2>
    <h3>Contact Us</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That gives me the correct colors on the correct text but the black box that run behind it the length of the screen disappears, Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: @ElijahDlubak I made an edit to my answer with a full snippet. Hopefully that works well for you.

Comment: Mizzy thank you so much! You are the best

Comment: No problem! Make sure to upvote and choose best answer if you feel I sufficiently answered your question :D Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

you forget something in your code HTML.

try to add class before `myCloud`
like this:

`class="myCloud"`

Comment: You are great! The only thing now is that the box starts after the text. Can I make the text overlay on top of the box?

Comment: your answer will not work for that question.